# Python regex findall alternation behavior

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm using Python 2.7.6. I can't understand the following result from `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.findall('\d|\(\d,\d\)', '(6,7)')
['(6,7)']
```

I expected the above to return `['6', '7']`, because according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> '|'
>
> A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular
>   expression that will match either A or B. An arbitrary number of REs
>   can be separated by the '|' in this way. This can be used inside
>   groups (see below) as well. As the target string is scanned, REs
>   separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern
>   completely matches, that branch is accepted. ***This means that once A
>   matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a
>   longer overall match.*** In other words, the '|' operator is never
>   greedy. To match a literal '|', use \|, or enclose it inside a
>   character class, as in [|].

Thanks for your help

Comment: `n [4]: re.findall(r'\d|\d,\d\)', '(6,7)') Out[4]: ['6', '7']` Amazing what difference the ( makes, eh? It found a possible match for the second thing first, so that's what got matched.

Comment: @hwnd The example is contrived, I'm trying to understand the expected behavior here.

Comment: "REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right." Maybe this means from left to right in the string? In this case, the `(` is more to the left than the first digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in document :

> This means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match.

So in this case regex engine doesn't match the `\d` because your string stars with `(` and not `\d` so it will match the second case that is `\(\d,\d\)`. But if your string stared with `\d` it would match `\d` :

```
>>> re.findall('\d|\d,\d\)', '6,7)')
['6', '7']
```

Comment: Comprehension dawns..:) Thanks.